# Problems installing Platformio IDE-terminal Atom

Tags: python, node.js, atom-editor, platformio

Running into an issue downloading the Platformio ide-terminal on Atom.  It used to work fine for me but recently stopped.  I tried to reinstall and it has failed every time.  I listed the output below.  Any ideas what I need to do to fix?

I have tried re-installing Visual Studio tools.  I also installed Node.js.  Nothing seems to be working.

```
Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed.Hide output…

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js


C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
  conpty.cc
  path_util.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8205,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\path_util.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8214,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\path_util.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8205,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\conpty.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8214,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\conpty.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1316,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\\conpty.node) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty.node). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty.vcxproj]
     Creating library C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty.lib and object C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty.exp
  Generating code
  Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
  All 951 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Finished generating code
  conpty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\\conpty.node
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
  conpty_console_list.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8205,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\conpty_console_list.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\6.1.12\include\node\v8.h(8214,1): warning C4996: 'v8::MicrotasksCompletedCallback': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\win\conpty_console_list.cc) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1316,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\\conpty_console_list.node) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty_console_list.node). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
     Creating library C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty_console_list.lib and object C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\conpty_console_list.exp
  Generating code
  Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
  All 167 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Finished generating code
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "link.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\obj\conpty_console_list\conpty_c.0678133A.tlog'. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(876,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\conpty_console_list.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty.vcxproj]
  AgentLocation.cc
  winpty.cc
  BackgroundDesktop.cc
  Buffer.cc
  DebugClient.cc
  GenRandom.cc
  OwnedHandle.cc
  StringUtil.cc
  WindowsSecurity.cc
  WindowsVersion.cc
  WinptyAssert.cc
  WinptyException.cc
  WinptyVersion.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1316,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\\winpty.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\winpty.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty.vcxproj]
     Creating library C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\winpty.lib and object C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\winpty.exp
  Generating code
  Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.
  All 1034 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
  Finished generating code
  winpty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\Release\\winpty.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
  Agent.cc
  AgentCreateDesktop.cc
  ConsoleFont.cc
  ConsoleInput.cc
  ConsoleInputReencoding.cc
  ConsoleLine.cc
  DebugShowInput.cc
  DefaultInputMap.cc
  EventLoop.cc
  InputMap.cc
  LargeConsoleRead.cc
  NamedPipe.cc
  Scraper.cc
  Terminal.cc
  Win32Console.cc
  Win32ConsoleBuffer.cc
  main.cc
  BackgroundDesktop.cc
  Buffer.cc
  DebugClient.cc
  GenRandom.cc
  OwnedHandle.cc
  StringUtil.cc
  WindowsSecurity.cc
  WindowsVersion.cc
  WinptyAssert.cc
  WinptyException.cc
  WinptyVersion.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\Release\obj\winpty-agent\winpty-agent.tlog'. [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles..ctor(ITaskItem[] tlogFiles) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(518,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj]

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=6.1.12 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\T Smith\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\T Smith\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\T Smith\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\TSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020918-6832-1wpugoc.m0wdf No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\T Smith\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-10-18T04_30_01_081Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Is re-installing the IDE feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'platformio-ide-terminal' wont be working any Longer with the latest versions of Atom.
I have found many other terminals which are failing with updated version Of Atom IDE

check this Link: https://community.platformio.org/t/cannot-install-platformio-terminal-in-atom/16617

Best Alterative Working Terminal :

X-terminal

https://atom.io/packages/x-terminal

Update -- 27-DEC-2020

After updating the ATOM IDE to version 1.53.0 the platformio ide terminal is working currently.

Link : https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal (Working version 2.10.1)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Open Atom IDE.
2. Open settings, and open Settings or preferences.
3. Search for platform-io-terminal in the package search and install it
4. Make sure that the plugin publisher is Platform-IO
5. Install it.
6. Restart the IDE or your computer.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do.  Every time I go to install the terminal it fails

Comment: did you try reinstalling Atom

Comment: Yep, tried that yesterday and didn't seem to do anything